# c++ linked list reversal - pointer doesn't advance

Tags: c++, linked-list

I know questions about reversing linked lists have been asked before but I want to try to figure this out with my own implementation.

My code makes sense to me and I feel it should work but when I run the debugger, the loop runs infinitely.  Specifically, `head` and `next` keep alternating between the first and second nodes of the linked list.   The `getLink()` method returns the pointer of the node (which is pointing to the next node in the list).  Any input based on my comments in under the while loop would help.

```
void revNodes(IntNodePtr& head)
{
    IntNodePtr prev = NULL;
    IntNodePtr next = NULL;
    next = head;
    while (next != NULL)
    {
        prev = head;
        // this should advance the pointer head to the next node in the list because next is the same as head initially
        head = next->getLink();
        // advance the pointer next to node after it
        next = next->getLink();
        // set the pointer in the node that head is pointing to to prev (head before head was advanced)
        head->setLink(prev);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You initialise `next` to `head` and then inside the loop you're setting them to both point to the **same** node.

Effectively, they're both pointing at the first node after the head of the list, you're then setting the pointer on that node to be the head of the list with the line `head->setLink(prev)`. Therefore, on your next pass through the loop, `head` and `next` both get pointed back at the original head node!

If you change:

```
next = next->getLink();
```

to:

```
next = head->getLink();
```

You'll be able to progress through the list, **but** then you'll jump the next node as you set `head` to `next->getLink()`. So at the start you should initialise `next` to be `head->getLink()`, set `head` to `next` inside the loop, and `next` to `head->getLink()` as above.

So turning that into code:

```
void revNodes(IntNodePtr& head)
{
    IntNodePtr prev = NULL;
    IntNodePtr next = NULL;
    next = head->getLink();
    while (next != NULL)
    {
        prev = head;
        // this should advance the pointer head to the next node in the list
        head = next;
        // advance the pointer next to node after it
        next = next->getLink();
        // set the pointer in the node that head is pointing to to prev (head before head was advanced)
        head->setLink(prev);
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense.  My initial strategy was to create a "copy" of `head` in the form of `next` so that I could point the pointer in the node that head was pointing to to the previous node and advance `next` at the same time.  However, I failed to realize that next and and head were pointing to the same node!

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
void revNodes(IntNodePtr&head)
{
    IntNodePtr prev = NULL;
    IntNodePtr next = NULL;
    IntNodePtr p = head;
    while (p){
        next = p->getLink();
        p->setLink(prev);
        prev = p;
        p = next;
    }
    head = prev;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your algorithm:

1. The head element in the list will become the last element in the reversed list, so you need to set its link to NULL.
2. In the first iteration in the loop you changed the link in the second item to point to the first, but you did not advance the `next` pointer to the following item (the third element in this case).